# npm command not found error but node is installed

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, homebrew, npm-install

I installed node and npm with Homebrew a while ago, they both worked fine until today when I keep running into the **npm command not found** error.

When is run **$ whereis node**, I get nothing back

When I do **$ which node**, I see **/usr/local/bin/node**

When I do **$ node -v**, I see **v4.4.7**

When I do **$ whereis npm**, I get nothing back

When I do **$ which npm**, I get nothing back

When I do **$ npm -v**, I see **-bash: npm: command not found**

I have tried

```
$ brew update
$ brew uninstall npm
$ brew install npm
```

I have also made sure that my `$NODE_PATH` environment variable is set:

```
# In ~/.bash_profile file:
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules"
```

I also followed these instructions from https://himanen.info/solved-npm-command-not-found/

Nothing seems to work and I keep getting **npm: command not found** when I run any command in any folder with npm. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Where is `npm` installed? Is this location in your `$PATH`?

Comment: You would use `brew ls --verbose npm` or `locate npm` to find where npm is installed

Comment: @jcaron when I run **brew ls --verbose npm**, it seems like it's installed under **/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.3.0/**

Comment: It would seem more logical for it to be in `/usr/local/bin` or someplace similar. Not using homebrew myself, but shouldn't you have run it using `sudo`?

Comment: @ is there a command I can use to put it in /usr/local/bin? When I try combining sudo with npm, I just get the **sudo: npm: command not found** error

Comment: I meant using `sudo` while installing. You can move files using `mv` or copy them using `cp` (or use the Finder!), however if one file is not in the right location, chances are you'll face the issue for more files.

Comment: Don't put solved in the title - just accept an answer instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Figured out the issue. So the root of the problem was that I installed npm using Homebrew and there are some issues with what goes on under the hood with Homebrew and npm.

To fix this I did the following:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

**Important!**
Do this in .bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH"
```

Now everything works like a charm

Comment: This is to fix the issue if Node and NPM paths are already messed up

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue, I am using a MAC.
It was a permission issue in my case, here is what I already did:

```
$ brew update
$ brew uninstall npm
$ brew install npm
```

That didn't work for me, so I tried this:

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib
$ brew postinstall node
```

and this linked installed node with npm, when I typed:

```
$ npm -v
5.3.0
```

Now all commands followed by NPM are working fine,
like `npm install`

Hope this will work for all!!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In mac via homebrew, when you are getting error like

```
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
```

or mostly getting several folder permission, don't give full permission like

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib
```

Please use as mentioned below

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

What it will do, simply gives the ownership to the user (linux users also can use this).

Hint: And in mac please use homebrew for installation. Advantages of homebrew you can switch between versions, easy to uninstall, you no need to run as root (sudo), like wise lots of advantages are there, as a developer its recommended to use homebrew (https://brew.sh/). And one more thing whenever you are getting some error like permission denied or something don't, give the full permission instead of using **chmod** use **chown**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I executed following command to install node and npm - it worked perfectly.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node
```